# Merge nested json values in php

Tags: php

In PHP, I am struggling to merge two json objects ( `$old` and `$new` ) with nested values:

```
echo "OLD: ".$old;

echo "NEW: ".$new;
```

Result:

```
OLD: {"4":{"deu":1, "eng":1, "fra":1}}
NEW: {"4":{"deu":1, "eng":2}}
```

Expected result I needed:

```
{"4":{"deu":1, "eng":2, "fra":1}}
```

Attempts:

Tried `json_decode()` and `array_merge()` but got a json result with missing key `4`

I got these kind of results:

```
{{"deu":1, "eng":2, "fra":1}} 
//or
[{"deu":1, "eng":1, "fra":1},{"deu":1, "eng":2}]
```

As you can see the key `4` is missing from the result

Comment: Not sure why you would expect that result from just concatenating the values? Have you actually made any real attempt to implement your requirement?

Comment: yes i tried multiple potental attempts with json_decode and array_merge but for i get a json result with missing key "4", in other words I get this {{"deu":1, "eng":2, "fra":1}} or this [{"deu":1, "eng":1, "fra":1},{"deu":1, "eng":2}] as you can see the key "4" is missing from the result

Comment: Show your best effort so far then, instead of the pointless code you provided above. Maybe you're actually not too far from the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `foreach()` as well along with `json_decode()` and `array_merge()`

```
<?php

$old = '{"4":{"deu":1, "eng":1, "fra":1}}';
$new = '{"4":{"deu":1, "eng":2}}';

$oldArray = json_decode($old,true);
$newArray = json_decode($new,true);


$finalArray =[];
foreach($oldArray as $key=>$value){
    $finalArray[$key] =  array_merge($value,$newArray[$key]);
}

print_r($finalArray);

echo json_encode($finalArray);
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/i0QLt